# How to best start a "related bounty"?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, bounty

I asked the question [How does one attack a divisibility problem like $(a+b)^2 \mid (2a^3+6a^2b+1)$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/538131/how-does-one-attack-a-divisibility-problem-like-ab2-mid-2a36a2b1). I received some excellent comments, one of which has, I believe, given me the idea(s) I need to proceed.

Now I would like to add a bounty on finding solutions, or bounds on solutions, to the divisibility condition in the title. (I currently know of only two.)

Should I add the bounty to the original question (even though the bounty is not specifically for answering it)? Or should I start a new thread — specifically titled so that it's clear that I'm looking for numerical solutions — and eventually attach the bounty there?

Thanks, Kieren.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The second option. You should not change the question in a major way, especially when you have answers. This is true even for old questions, like this one.

If you want to ask a new (related) question, then you should ask it in a new post and link back to the original.

Comment: Thanks! I will do that. Best, Kieren.